# Devise signin/signup failure error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, devise

I have created a simple application with Foundation 5 and Devise support. 
I noticed that messages for Sign In and Sign Up failures are displayed differently. 
Foundation 5 has generated the following partial for displaying flash messages:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
   <div data-alert class="alert-box round <%= name == :notice ? "success" : "alert" %>">
    <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
   </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have Googled and read many posts but none of them answer my questions.

I have the following questions:

1) As far as I understand Sign In failure messages are automatically put in the flash hash while Sign Up failure messages are not. Am I right?

2) If so, what is rationale behind it? I mean, why are Sign In failure messages are automatically added to the flash but Sign Up and Send Me Reset Password are not?

3) I want to put all generated Devise messages into the flash so that the partial will display it. So far, the only way I have come up with is to override `devise_error_messages!`   ,scan the `resource.errors.full_messages` and put them into flash. Does anyone know a better method to do it?

This is how I overrode `devise_error_messages!`:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
   return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    flash.now[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages.first

    return ""
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) As far as I understand Sign In failure messages are automatically put in the flash hash while Sign Up failure messages are not. Am I right?

Indeed.

> 2) If so, what is rationale behind it? I mean, why are Sign In failure messages are automatically added to the flash but Sign Up and Send Me Reset Password are not?

When creating/updating the User model (or the model used for Devise), the error are going to be showed like form errors. Login/Logout doesn't modify the model, so a flash message is shown instead.

Also, (particularly for `Sign Up`) showing a big unformatted paragraph with several error messages at the top (where usually the flash messages lie) doesn't seem like a good idea, compared to having a special `<div>` just on top of the form having the attributes and errors showed in a pretty format.

> 3) I want to put all generated Devise messages into the flash so that the partial will display it. So far, the only way I have come up with is to override devise_error_messages! ,scan the resource.errors.full_messages and put them into flash. Does anyone know a better method to do it?

If you still want to use a flash message to show the error messages, the code you're showing only gives you the first error message, not all.

Try something like this:

```
flash.now[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages.join(" ")
```

Or even better, since `devise_error_messages!` is called from the view for the form:

1. remove that call on the view (you'll probably need to generate the views from Devise).
2. use `flash[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages.join(" ")` on the Controller.

Comment: Agree, I think modifying Controller is better than overriding `devise_error_messages` and calling from every view.

Comment: However, the problem is that I don't know beforehand which messages are automatically added to flash and which not. Are they described anywhere in docs? So I don't know what methods should be overridden. Rewriting all controller's methods isn't a good idea either. So using `devise_error_messages` seems to be inevitable.

Comment: When creating/updating the User model (or the model used for Devise), the error are going to be showed like form errors. Login/Logout doesn't modify the model, so a flash message is shown instead. Reset password errors are also shown in the form, AFAIK.

Comment: I took a look at Devise source code. There are at least 6 controller files. So, do you think it is a good idea to open each file and override each method of the controllers (those which generate messages)? To make things worse, they are not documented at all (like, say, ActiveModel on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).

Comment: As to your answers, they at least shed light on some details of Devise. Thank you!

Comment: I still don't understand, why can't you use flash messages for Sign In/Sign Out and use form validation errors for Sign Up/Reset Password?

Comment: In fact I can use, but my aim is to handle Devise messages and all other messages in my application exceptionally through flash. The `messages.html.erb` partial is the only place where I want to display messages (be they of Devise or other controller) and `flash` is the only place from where I want to pop messages. This is just an approach. I want to keep message generating and displaying compact as much as possible. Am I clear?

Comment: You can store flash messages in a variable in the controller, but I'm not sure it's a good idea from the user experience standpoint

Comment: I think it would be great if Devise stuck to some kind of "uniform" approach concerning messages. Instead, I have to check both flash and resource error message array to format and display messages. Wouldn't it be easier if I knew with certainty that all messages are in flash or should be pop from resource error message array?

Comment: I don't agree. Flash messages are for short messages. Errors for forms are long and need some kind of formatting, preferably showing the input that caused the error. These are different kind of messages, and they should be treated differently.

Comment: I agree. In this case `devise_error_messages!` is the best place where I could intercept validation errors and push into flash.

Comment: I was mad at this. But in fact, now it makes sense. Thanks.